# Map over two arrays to see if one property matches, then push specific info into the first array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach, array.prototype.map

New to javascript and trying to learn! I am trying to map through two array of objects, and if a certain property matches, pull in specific information into the first array.

```
let result;

let arrNames = [{
  id: 10  
  name: "A"
}, {
  id: 11,
  name: "B"
}, {
  id: 12,
  name: "C"
}, }, {
  id: 13,
  name: "A"
}, {
  id: 14,
  name: "B"
}]

let arrInfo = [{
  name: "A",
  info: "AAA"
}, {
  name: "B",
  info: "BBB"
}, {
  name: "C",
  info: "CCC"
}]
```

If arrNames.name == arrInfo.name, I would like push info into the names array.

Desired result:

```
let arrNames = [{
  id: 10  
  name: "A",
  info: "AAA"
}, {
  id: 11,
  name: "B",
  info: "BBB"
}, {
  id: 12,
  name: "C",
  info: "CCC"
}, }, {
  id: 13,
  name: "A",
  info: "AAA"
}, {
  id: 14,
  name: "B",
  info: "BBB"
}]
```

What I've tried:

```
const res = arrInfo.map((el, index) => {
      if(el.name == arrNames[index].name) 
        arrNames.push(el.info)
    }
```

^ This obviously doesn't work -- but I'm wondering if extend or push would be appropriate here.

Thanks in advance for your help (apologies that this is probably a dupe).

Comment: Do google about map vs filter vs forEach.

Comment: @Ejaz47 appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `arrInfo` to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), with the `name` as the key. Now [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) `arrNames` and add the info you get from `arrInfoMap` using the `name`. Use [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) to combine both objects:

```js
const arrNames = [{"id":10,"name":"A"},{"id":11,"name":"B"},{"id":12,"name":"C"},{"id":13,"name":"A"},{"id":14,"name":"B"}]

const arrInfo = [{"name":"A","info":"AAA"},{"name":"B","info":"BBB"},{"name":"C","info":"CCC"}]

const arrInfoMap = new Map(arrInfo.map(o => [o.name, o]))

const result = arrNames.map(o => ({ ...o, ...arrInfoMap.get(o.name) }))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: thanks for the approach! However, result ends up just being the original arrNames array, without the arrInfo.info. Would this approach change if the key was different (in my case i'm trying to match "workflow_name" with "legal_authority", rather than "name" and "name".

Comment: You can see that the code snippet result (click run code snippet) includes the `info` field. Change the the property you use for the Map's key, and then use it when you get from the Map.

Comment: Thing to note - this solution complexity is O(n + m) (combined lengths of both arrays), while map + filter, or map + forEach are O(n * m).

Comment: answered my own questions. I just make the keys the same and it worked perfectly. Thank you again!

Comment: @BWeb303 this is a good answer but check out mine if you want a clearer approach in terms of logic if you are still new to javascript. Here the OP uses the spread operator and single line arrow functions which implicitly returns the right side of the function, which you seem to be confused with as you are using `push` in your map instead of returning something which map requires you to do to create a new array. You are using `map` like a `forEach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
let arrNames = [
  {
    id: 10,
    name: 'A'
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    name: 'B'
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    name: 'C'
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    name: 'A'
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    name: 'B'
  }
];

let arrInfo = [
  {
    name: 'A',
    info: 'AAA'
  },
  {
    name: 'B',
    info: 'BBB'
  },
  {
    name: 'C',
    info: 'CCC'
  }
];

// do this
const result = arrNames.map((item) => {
  const newItem = item; // here we define a new object that is the same as your object that is currently looped up to in your arrNames array

  // loop your second array over this currently looped to object, seeing if the name matches
  arrInfo.forEach((item2) => {
    if (item.name === item2.name) {
      newItem.info = item2.info; // if they do set a new property for your new object called info as the info from item 2 of this arrInfo array
    }
  });

  // return this new object whether or not there was a match for the name property
  return newItem; 
});

console.log(result);
```

So the thing with your map method is that you need to remember to return something at the end of your callback function. You are simply pushing to an array, which is like using `.map` as a `forEach`. Map makes one array into another array of the same length. Here you are trying to make a new array where the array element being looped over will have an extra `info` property should it match your second array `arrInfo`'s name.

So you what you can do is a forEach inside your map to check if they match, if so add a new property to your arrayNames element and return that as the new element for your newly created array. Hope that helped, please ask for clarifications if you need in the comments.

Comment: this makes sense — thank you so much for taking the time to explain my error!